# Custom sort for US date format is not working using J-query datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Issue with jquery datatables sorting: Hi i'm using the below code for sorting the US dates in table columns, but its not working...

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['custom_us_date-asc'] = function(x, y) {
    var xVal = getCustomEuroDateValue(x);
    var yVal = getCustomEuroDateValue(y);

    if (xVal < yVal) {
        return -1;
    } else if (xVal > yVal) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['custom_us_date-desc'] = function(x, y) {
    var xVal = getCustomEuroDateValue(x);
    var yVal = getCustomEuroDateValue(y);

    if (xVal < yVal) {
        return 1;
    } else if (xVal > yVal) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}


    function getCustomEuroDateValue(strDate) {
    var frDatea = $.trim(strDate).split(' ');
    var frTimea = frDatea[1].split(':');
    var frDatea2 = frDatea[0].split('/');

    var x = (frDatea2[2] + frDatea2[1] + frDatea2[0] + frTimea[0] + frTimea[1]);
    x = x * 1;

    return x;
}



function tableDef(){
     oTable = j$('#example').dataTable({
            "bPaginate":false,
            "bJQueryUI": true,         
            "aoColumns": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                {"stype" :"custom_us_date",
                    "fnRender" : function(obj, val)
                {
                    if(j$(val).text() != '')
                    {
                        var d = new Date(j$(val).text());

                        var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
                        var sMonth = '';
                        if(month < 10) sMonth = '0' + month; else sMonth =                       month;
                        var day = d.getDate();
                        var sDay = '';
                        if(day < 10) sDay = '0' + day; else sDay = day;
                        var sYear = d.getFullYear();
                        var hour = d.getHours();
                        var sHour = '';
                        if(hour < 10) sHour = '0' + hour; else sHour = hour;
                        var minute = d.getMinutes();
                        var sMinute = '';
                        if(minute < 10) sMinute = '0' + minute; else sMinute =                        minute;
                        var finalString = sMonth + '/' + sDay + '/' + sYear  + ' ' + sHour + ':' + sMinute;

                         return finalString;
                                }
```

but it is not doing custom sort(date), its just doing string sort. Its  not at all considering the custom sort for dates. I'm formatting the date in fnRender to US date format then returning the value to custom sort function using sType.

I'm very new to j-query, if you can update my code, it would be highly appreciated....

Thanks for looking....

Answer (score 0):

hey i try this with some customize to my code, hope this help you :

```
$.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
"date-custom-pre": function(a) {
var x;
try {
    var dateA = a.replace(/ /g, '').split("-");
    var Datetime = a.replace(/ /g, '').split(",");
    var timeA = Datetime[1];//time hour:minute
    var timeB = timeA.replace(/ /g, '').split(":");// split hour & minute
    var hour = timeB[0];
    var minute = timeB[1].replace(/\D/g, '');// remove string after "hour:minute"

    var day = parseInt(dateA[0], 10);
    var month = parseInt(dateA[1], 10);
    var year = parseInt(dateA[2], 10);
    var date = new Date(year, month - 1, day, hour, minute);
    x = date.getTime();
}
catch (err) {
    x = new Date().getTime();
}

return x;
},
   "date-custom-asc": function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
},
   "date-custom-desc": function(a, b) {
    return b - a;
}});
```

how to use :

```
$('#table').DataTable({
"aaData": data,
"order": [[0, "desc"]], //default sort column on first page loaded
"aoColumnDefs": [
    { sType: "date-custom", aTargets: [0] } //based on your date column
],
"aoColumns": [
    {"mDataProp": "date_save"
        ,"mRender": function(data, type, full)
        {
            var getData = new Date(data);
            var month = getData.getMonth() + 1;
            var date = getData.getDate();
            var year = getData.getFullYear();
            var hour = getData.getHours();
            var minute = getData.getMinutes();

            return (date > 9 ? date : "0" + date) + "-" +
                   (month > 9 ? month : "0" + month) + "-" + 
                   year + 
                   ", " + 
                   (hour > 9 ? hour : "0" + hour) + ":" +
                   (minute > 9 ? minute : "0" + minute);
        }
    },
    {"mDataProp": "source_page"},
    {"mDataProp": "sub_status"}
]});
```

it will show date format like this :

```
15-12-2016, 12:33 -> (dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm)
```